# mimic form upload jquery with existing server file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form here :

http://www.3dgallery.ir/Themes/default/script/stl2image/

I need to change the uploading part to a automatic uploading method.

It means that I have the files on my server and I want the functionality of changing stl files to image on cloud.

So I thought if I auto post the url of the file through a form it can generate that image !

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="posthandler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" border="1px">  
        <table>
        <tr><td>
        <img id="stl2image" src="css/images/image_100x100.png" alt="STL to Image !" width="100px" height="100px">
        </td>   </tr>
        <tr><td>
        Upload Your STL file here.
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
        <img id="loading" src="http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif" alt="Please wait.." />
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

But files are already uploaded on my server :

[www.3dgallery.ir/Data/Things/rod-flexible.stl](http://www.3dgallery.ir/Data/Things/rod-flexible.stl)

I don't need the upload browse , I just need the script to auto post of my urls

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to change the input type to text and send the url but I couldn't  make it . http://www.3dgallery.ir/Themes/default/script/stl2image/index2.html